# Store a NodeJS server request and response for later use

Tags: node.js, express, http, middleware, http-proxy

Currently I have this very simple proxy server:

```
const http = require('http');
const proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer();

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:9000' });
  })
  .listen(8999);
```

It listens on port 8999, passes the same request to port 9000 and returns the answer to port 8999.

*The goal is to get rid of server on port 9000.*

**I wish to record the server responses (save to a file or database) and use port 8999 server as a mock server.**

What options are available on **Node v6**? Middlewares, or any hacks are welcome.

I have an Express.js version of this, where I could record the request and response, but can not handle redirections and possible nether any more complicated scenarios. But I guess I don't need to reinvert the wheel and someone already has a solution for this.

**All sorts of data can flow through**, like simple JSON in GET request, but POST, DELETE and other methods can be present with redirections, file attachments, etc.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve though? More context as to the issue would help in understanding why you want to do this as it may be possible with NGINX, so if the server is live with an NGINX front end you could just use NGINX

Comment: @proxim0 NGINX is a good idea, but can you save the requests?

Comment: @proxim0 I want to separate the frontend from the backend so that I could create a mock backend with static data. Currently I need to run a backend server in order to test the frontend.

Comment: @eErik Kránicz I'm still a little confused, is this just an API that you want to funnel data to on a specific port and then consume the data on a mobile device or website via API calls, or does it do more then that? For the NGINX question, Using NGINX to proxy pass to a backend node server will simply pass the request to your node app going from say 80 --> 9000 or what ever port you want and your application will handle the request then. You mention testing a mock backend, what issue are you running into running it locally this way?

Comment: @proxim0 So, we have front-end static files (HTML, JS) served with Nginx on the local machine. But some of the requests are proxied to a different port, and served with a Java back end. We don't have a mock server and the back end is huge, but if anyone is working with the back end it blocks the front end. So, I wish to replace the Java back end with a mock server in order that I could work on the front end uninterrupted. Because the Java back end is huge, I don't want to write each and every calls, instead record them and after switching from Java to the mock I would serve the same responses.